# How do i pass a var from v-for back through onclick to a method?

Tags: methods, vue.js

How do i pass a var from v-for back through onclick to a method?

HTML snippet:

```
<div v-for="image in images" class="addImg">
                    <img  class="img-thumbnail" @click="addImage({{image.url}}) v-bind:src="image.url">
                    <span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> add</span>
                </div>
```

Script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        newImages: false,

        images: [
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image1.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image2.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image3.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image4.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image5.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image6.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image7.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image8.jpg' },
            { url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/image9.jpg' }
        ]

    },
    methods: {
        addImage : function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Chrome console error:

"attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes."

the documentation says "Note that attribute interpolations are disallowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes. Don’t worry, Vue.js will raise warnings for you when mustaches are used in wrong places."

I got the warning, but still cant see how to pass it back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the brackets:

```
@click="addImage(image.url)"
```